In what order should I watch the Hunger Games films?
I haven't yet read or watched The Hunger Games.  I am now thinking of watching the movies.
Are they chronological, or can I watch them in any order?

A pretty good question, especially since the latest one is a prequel.

Yes, this seems a very reasonable question. I don’t understand downvoters.

Movies
In brief, the cinematic release order is fine, and probably to be recommended.
The four original movies (The Hunger Games, The Hunger Games: Catching Fire, The Hunger Games: Mockingjay – Part 1 and The Hunger Games: Mockingjay – Part 2)  were released in the same sequence as the in-universe chronology, so it makes zero sense to watch them in any other order.
Where things get tricky is that the latest instalment (The Hunger Games: The Ballad of Songbirds & Snakes) is a prequel, set approximately 64 years before the events of the first Hunger Games film. The film's director suggests that if you're new to the franchise, that you can watch his film first, but that he would still recommend that you watch the originals before coming to his, in order to get the fullest flavour.

The latest entry in the Hunger Games franchise might take place before the events of the previous films – but director Francis Lawrence reckons it would still make sense for viewers to watch the original movies first.
"I will say, I think part of what's fun is if you hadn't seen any of
the movies, or read any of the other books, you can watch this story
and, I think, find it engaging and find it fulfilling as a standalone
movie."
But he added: "I think if you've seen the other movies... part of the
fun of this one is there's so many elements that are sort of the
origins of things – the origins of characters, the origins of
character dynamics, the origins of songs we know from the other one,
you know, a lot of little Easter eggs.
"[So] it might actually be better to watch this one after [the
originals], if you've never seen them. Because I think you'll just
have this other level of enjoyment of feeling the origins of things."
Hunger Games prequel director reveals best order to watch films in

The film series' producer is also of a similar mind. You can watch the prequel as a stand-alone film, or watch it after seeing the whole series.

Nina Jacobson – who has produced each instalment in the franchise –
said that it was important to the filmmakers that the [prequel] movie was
accessible to both newcomers and old fans.
"But we want this movie to work if you know nothing about the books or
the movies, but you know that it is worthy of a trip to the cinema."
She added: "What we also wanted to make sure [is] that if you are a
fan, that there was like a whole bunch of stuff for you to find and
enjoy, and Easter eggs and origin stories and details. So that we
could serve both."


Novels
The three original novels (The Hunger Games, Catching Fire, and Mockingjay) represent a single in-universe story released in broadly chronological order. As with the film series, it makes no sense to read these in any other order than in which they were published.
The author followed these up with a prequel novel; The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes. In similar fashion to the film series, it's possible to read this as a stand-alone novel but in order to appreciate some subtle 'easter eggs' and avoid a minor spoiler, this should be read after reading the three original novels.

Books Vs. Movies
Suzanne Collins has repeatedly stated in interviews that she holds no strong opinion over whether you should watch the movies first or read the books. They're both pretty faithful to the story she originally created, and she's been heavily involved in the writing and production of the film series.

David Levithan: Do you picture your characters as you’re writing them? If so, how
close did Jennifer Lawrence come to the Katniss in your head? And now
when you think about Katniss, do you see Jennifer or do you still see
what you imagined before?
Suzanne Collins: I definitely do picture the characters
when I’m writing them. The actress who looks exactly like my book
Katniss doesn’t exist. Jennifer looked close enough and felt very
right, which is more important. She gives an amazing performance. When
I think of the books, I still think of my initial image of Katniss.
When I think of the movies, I think of Jen. Those images aren’t at war
any more than the books are with the films. Because they’re faithful
adaptations, the story becomes the primary thing. Some people will
never read a book, but they might see the same story in a movie. When
it works well, the two entities support and enrich each other.
Suzanne Collins Talks About ‘The Hunger Games,’ the Books and the Movies

